# what are the possibilities for playing music with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am making an assignment for school involving a raspberry pi controlling a house installation but I would like to expand on this assignment for those sweet bonus points and just because it's fun.
I was thinking about playing music using the pi but I have no clue where to start and I would like to know some possibilities so maybe you can help. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a possible job for a buzzer if you need a simple working solution with gpiozero... Also if your not looking for a pythonic/embedded way you can use omxplayer which you can install through the pi by using :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install omxplayer
```

If you copy an mp3 over to the pi you will be able to play it through omxplayer. But as i said aboe if you are looking for a bread board based solution for the sound it could get more involved dealing with the possible DAC to ge the sound to output correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I put some music in background using the mplayer software in a raspberry pi connected to a screen via HDMI.

This is the command that I used:
`mplayer -noconsolecontrols http://sj128.hnux.com </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

- http://sj128.hnux.com is the url of an online radio
- -noconsolecontrols prevents MPlayer from reading key events from standard input
- </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 redirect the input and the output

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a code similar to python developed mainly for music, I recommend `Sonic Pi` - it's pre-installed with Raspbian, I think, and I tried it a few years ago and it's not bad - worth giving it a go as you can export programs and therefore link them, and it's a quick way to write music through code.